# Finding the distance between 2 points fails

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm cycling through points in a geodataframe by index in such away where I am comparing index 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, then 3 and 4 etc... The purpose is to compare the 2 points. if the points are occupying the same location pass, else draw a line between the 2 points and summarize some stats. I figured if I compared the distance between the 2 points and got 0 then that would be skipped. What I have done before was to pass the 2 points in a single geodataframe into a function that returns a value for distance. They are in a projected crs units metres.

```
def getdist(pt_pair):
    shift_pt = pt_pair.shift()
    return pt_pair.distance(shift_pt)[1]
```

When I pass my 2 points to the function the first 2 return 0.0 the next return nan then I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/.../vessel_track_builder.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(getdist(set_pts))
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/.../vessel_track_builder.py", line 19, in getdist
if math.isnan(mdist1.distance(shift_pt)[1]):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 997, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1004, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thought this might be an error in the point geometry so I added an if nan return 0 to the function.

```
def getdist(pt_pair):
    shift_pt = pt_pair.shift()
    if math.isnan(pt_pair.distance(shift_pt)[1]):
        return 0
    else:
        return pt_pair.distance(shift_pt)[1]
```

The result is 0.0, 0, then the aforementioned error.

I added a print statement of my geodataframes but didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

```
 index      ...  MMSI MONTH                         geometry
0     92    ...   123   4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)
1     39    ...   123   4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)

[2 rows x 12 columns]

 index          ... MMSI MONTH                         geometry
1     39        ...  456  4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)
2   3231        ...  456  4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)

[2 rows x 12 columns]

 index         ... MMSI MONTH                         geometry
2   3231       ...  789  4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)
3   1032       ...  789  4  POINT (2221098.494 1668358.870)
```

I tried it on some test data with simple points and it went through them fine so I am wondering if there is something with how I am passing the geodataframe to the function. Since I am trying to compare each point to the one after it I am using the index to keep the order, could that be the issue?

```
for mmsi in points_gdf.MMSI.unique():
    track_pts = points_gdf[(points_gdf.MMSI == mmsi)].sort_values(['POSITION_UTC_DATE']).reset_index()
    print(track_pts.shape[0])
    for index, row in track_pts.iterrows():
        if index + 1 < track_pts.shape[0]:
            set_pts = track_pts[(track_pts.index == index) | (track_pts.index == index + 1)]
            print(set_pts)
            print(getdist(set_pts))
        else:
            sys.exit()
```

I am noticing the index header which when I look at the data in QGIS there is no index column the first column is OBJECTID and the data is stored in a filegeodatabase. Could the index column be causing me the issue?

Comment: why do you have `[1]` after getting the distance? what's this supposed to be indexing? given that you're getting a keyerror, I assume that's the issue. and does `math.isnan` even work on geometries?

Comment: ohhhh I think I see what you're doing. you're trying to positionally index into the differences, because in each loop you're taking the distance between each row and the next one. the trouble is that it's still a GeoSeries, so indexing by default will reference the index label, not the position. this works on the first go-around because the second index label actually is 1. but you should be using `pt_pair.distance(shift_pt).iloc[1]`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Did you want to post it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each pair of points, do this once:

```py
dist_to_next_point = track_pts.distance(track_pts.shift()).dropna()
```

Comment: I incorporated your answer into the function but the output was "none". As for looping, getting the distance and the result determines if I am drawing a line between the 2 and getting stats on the df values or skipping to the next point in the series. If 0 and 1 have a distance of 0 then I want to check 0 and 2 if they have a distance that is suitable a line will be drawn and I will check 2 and 3 and so on. In order to do that I think I need the loop.